# laravel file does not exist or is not readable

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to send zip file in laravel but i receive this error:

[image: one]

## Issue

When I upload my file it uploads, my database also gets updates, so basically no problem with physical file nor database data -- the only issue is that i receive this error somehow!

## Code

Here is my controller code

```
public function sendCompanyData(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, array(
            'coDoc' => 'required|mimetypes:application/zip|max:10000',
        ));

        $company = CompanyData::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first();
        //file
        if ($request->hasFile('coDoc')) {
            $coDoc = $request->file('coDoc');
            $filename = $company->user->username . '-Company-Prove-Documents-' . str_random(10) . '-' . time() . '.' . $coDoc->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $location = public_path('files/idus/');
            $request->file('coDoc')->move($location, $filename);


            $oldFilename = $company->files;
            $company->files = $filename;
            if(!empty($company->files)){
                Storage::delete($oldFilename);
            }

            $company->files = $filename;
        }
        $company->save();

        //send confirmation mail
        $userMail = $company->user->email;
        $data = array(
            'id' => $company->id,
            'user' => $company->user->username,
            'files' => url('files/idus', $company->files),
            'submit_time' => $company->created_at->format('d M, Y | H:m:s A'),
        );
        Mail::to($userMail)->send(new MailToAdmin($data));

        return redirect()->back();
}
```

**Any idea?**

Comment: The problem occurr when function try to delete the file. Fist check the availability of Tmp folder and also remove delete area from the function and then try again . Then please let us know what happens

Comment: @NipunTharuksha you mean error comes from `Storage::delete($oldFilename);`? but it is inside if statement `if(!empty($company->files)){`

Comment: Yes when you check it the file already uploaded to their server and then the condition comes true . Just change it as empty and check

Comment: Ok. I removed everything related to delete/replacement file and just left `$company->files = $filename;` yet is same error

Comment: Is temp folder available in public folder

Comment: @NipunTharuksha nope, not in public folder nor in files folder not even in idus folder

Comment: Hm then I’ll add a answer give me few minutes

Comment: could you please tell me what is your laravel version

Comment: I have tested your code and no errors are generating. Did you tried with clearing cache?

Answer (score 14):

You need to check if you have an error like:
"The file "***.jpg" exceeds your upload_max_filesize ini directive (limit is 2048 KiB)."

like `$coDoc->getErrorMessage()`

Comment: where is ini directive?

Comment: @Saddan it is located in /etc/php/cli/php.ini something like that

Answer (score 7):

check your php.ini...make sure that your upload_max_filesize is as big as your post_max_size.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/31249

Answer (score 5):

I fix it!

Do not use `move` function for save your file

I use `Storage::disk('public')->putFileAs` and work

I think can't move tmp file in Laravel version 6!

Comment: I have no idea why but this also solved it for me, Laravel 5.5.  My old code stopped working and started throwing this error, maybe after upgrading from 5.4, not sure.  Changing `$image->move()` to `$request->file('file')->storeAs()` fixes it again!